# Cartesian coordinates question

Tags: geometry

Do all three axes ($x$,$y$,and $z$) have to be at right angles to each other in order to have a unique position of all points in 3D space?

Comment: no. oblique coordinate systems are also used. (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ObliqueCoordinates.html)

Comment: All you need is that none of the axes is pointing in a direction that is contained in the plane that contains the other two.

Comment: Relevant: [Linear Independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence) and [Basis Vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra))

Comment: Just spread your thumb, your forefinger and your middle finger and meditate for some time.